# Update JSON from database in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, database

Aim: User clicks a button it retrieves latest record of json from database and updates state of green led to 1

Here whats I have so far, all code in one file index.php

The php code

```
$sql = "SELECT json FROM `smartlight` ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
```

Then html

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" onclick="myFunction()">More Options</a>
```

Then javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){

    var emparray = <?php echo json_encode($emparray) ?>;

    console.log ( emparray );

    for (var i=0; i<emparray.length; i++) {
        if (emparray[i].device == "greenled") {
                emparray[i].state= "1";
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log ( emparray );

}

</script>
```

Both console.log produces the same thing...

```
"{"smartdevices":[{"device":"greenled", "state":"0"},{"device":"redled", "state":"1"}]}"
```

Is it because in my javascript im trying to loop through something that isn't yet in the right state to be looped like this?

Thanks in advance

[console.log ( emparray );](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmz6G.png)

Comment: You can't mix JavaScript and PHP like this. PHP is rendered server side, when the request is made, JavaScript happens AFTER the page is loaded. You need to look into Ajax.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: @OptimusCrime that is not an issue here

Comment: Look for something like: `emparray[].smartdevices[i].device == "greenled"`

Comment: @charlietfl Oh, I might have misunderstood. He just wants to show something that is rendered beforehand when he clicks the button? In that case you are correct. I thought this was a classic case of dynamic data loading without the use of ajax.

Comment: @OptimusCrime Plan was to change it in javascript and then update the database with a new record with the updated JSON, then the page would refresh, it doesn't need to be a live update with no refreshes etc. Is Ajax still the answer?

Comment: @cameronmd you will need to send that update to server if you plan to store it. Ajax would be best for that

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah just not got to that yet, 1 step at a time. Assuming its possible to add a new record to the database with the new json without ajax, why would ajax be best for this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content from your database is a string. You need to decode the string first so your entire PHP array is evaluated when you run `json_encode`.

First, alter your PHP code like this:

```
//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    // Decode the string here
    $emparray[] = json_decode($row['json']);
}
```

You now need to loop the outer array, then the code inside.

Something like this:

```
// Loop the outer array (each part of $row)
for (var i = 0; i < emparray.length; i++) {
    // Loop each part of the 'smartdevices' array
    for (var j = 0; j < emparray[i]['smartdevices'].length; j++) {
        if (emparray[i]['smartdevices'][j]['device'] == "greenled") {
            emparray[i]['smartdevices'][j]['state'] = "1";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: @cameronmd Are you sure you have the correct output from the `console.log` commands? They way you create your JSON I suspect it should look different.

Comment: The console says [_Object_] then when I expand it, its says json: "{"smartdevices":[{"device":"greenled", "state":"0"},{"device":"redled", "state":"1"}]}"

Comment: Please expand the object, take a print screen and attach it to your original question. There is something wrong with the structure that I am not getting.

Comment: Done, I may have got something wrong in the JSON, is the 'smartdevices' part necessary?

Comment: @cameronmd Ah, now I see. You have a json object with a string inside. Hold on, let me change my answer.

Comment: @cameronmd Try again

Comment: No luck, first console.log is now [_null_] and then "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'smartdevices' of null"
Do I still need something like this:
var emparray = <?php echo json_encode($emparray) ?>;

Comment: @cameronmd Oh yeah, I've updated my PHP code to `json_decode($row['json']);`.

Comment: Nice that's it working now, thanks a lot! Now to package it back  up and add it back to the database... any tips on where to get started with that?

Comment: @cameronmd I'd create a method that take the value of `i`, `j` and the new value of `state` and then sends it using ajax to a PHP script. There are many approaches to this.